# Repeating DOM elements when appending

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to put an array of character images into the DOM using jquery.

jquery

```
    for (var i = 0; i < character.length; i ++) {
     let combatantChoice = $('<div>');
     combatantChoice.addClass('col-md-3 
     characterClass');
     $('#combatant-choice').append(combatantChoice);
     let combatantsImage = $('<img>');
     combatantsImage.addClass('character-image');
     combatantsImage.attr('src', character[i].image);
     $('.characterClass').append(combatantsImage);
    };
```

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div id="combatants-area" class="col-md-12">
    <div id="combatant-choice" class="row"></div>      
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Four divs with a .characterClass will show up as per length of the array of objects.

The problem is that the images will repeat in the .characterClass itself. So I end up with 4 images, 3 images, 2 images, one image. How can I stop that iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's creating 1, then 2, then 3, then 4 (etc) because of this line:

```
$('.characterClass').append(combatantsImage);
```

this selects all divs with ".characterClass".  The first time, there's only 2, the 2nd time, there's the one from the first time and the 2nd time, so it now adds it twice.

Instead, use:

```
combatantChoice.append(combatantsImage);
```

so that the image is only appended to the div that is being created within the loop.

Comment: I did upvote. This is the message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I only have 10 reputations at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - I wasn't aware of that - I've upvoted your question to give you more rep :)